# Can we use Selenium 3 to drive browser on remote machine?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Since in Selenium 3 (maybe include Selenium 2), test application calls API to talk with Web Drivers in WebDriver protocol, which is actually in HTTP. One obvious mind pop out is to use it to control Web Drivers And Browser on remote machine.

But after googling, surprisingly, I did not found any articles mention about that.

Is that impossible?

Comment: it is possible and there are many guides. Search for selenium grid. [check this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download selenium standalone server from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). And write in command line of the machine where you want to start the tests from this command

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role hub -port 8888`

Then go to the remote machine and download chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) open command line and write

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone--<version>.jar -port 8888 -role node -hub http://ipOfservermachine:8888/grid/register -browser browserName=c
hrome, binary=C:\\pathtochrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\pathtochromedriver`

For other browsers its the same but change path and driver