# Connecting Local Browser to Headless Server with Selenium 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to connect a browser running on a local machine to a remote machine running Selenium 4 server as a kind of proxy?

I'd like to interface with a browser window on a local machine but have a remote machine connect to the internet.

I found a post discussing how to do this with [Selenium 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438708/can-we-use-selenium-3-to-drive-browser-on-remote-machine/41441844#41441844) but I can't make manage to make it work with Selenium 4.

On the remote headless machine I'm running

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.18.1.jar hub --host server.ip.address
```

On the local machine I've tried running a few things, eg.

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.18.1.jar node --hub http://server.ip.address:4443/grid/register --driver-configuration display-name="Chrome" webdriver-path="C:\Users\localuser\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\122.0.6261.128\chromedriver.exe" stereotype="{\"browserName\": \"Chrome\", \"browserVersion\": \"122\" : {\"binary\":\"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\"}}"
```

This is the error output from the line above being run:

```
02:26:35.475 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
02:26:35.479 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
02:26:35.613 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://server.ip.address:4442 and tcp://server.ip.address:4443
02:26:35.649 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
02:26:36.663 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
02:26:36.765 INFO [NodeServer.createHandlers] - Reporting self as: http://client.ip.address:5555
02:26:36.785 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 16 available processors
02:26:36.786 INFO [NodeOptions.discoverDrivers] - Looking for existing drivers on the PATH.
02:26:36.786 INFO [NodeOptions.discoverDrivers] - Add '--selenium-manager true' to the startup command to setup drivers automatically.
02:26:37.116 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - There was an error managing chromedriver (Unable to discover proper chromedriver version in offline mode); using driver found in the cache
02:26:37.417 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - There was an error managing msedgedriver (Unable to discover proper msedgedriver version in offline mode); using driver found in the cache
02:26:37.744 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - There was an error managing geckodriver (Unable to discover proper geckodriver version in offline mode); using driver found in the cache
02:26:37.744 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - There was an error managing firefox; using browser found in the cache
02:26:38.047 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - There was an error managing IEDriverServer (Unable to discover proper IEDriverServer version in offline mode); using driver found in the cache
02:26:38.064 ERROR [Bootstrap.runMain] - Error during execution
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Bootstrap.runMain(Bootstrap.java:77)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:70)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.ConfigException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.getClass(MemoizedConfig.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.getNode(NodeOptions.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.createHandlers(NodeServer.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.asServer(NodeServer.java:185)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.execute(NodeServer.java:247)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.TemplateGridCommand.lambda$configure$4(TemplateGridCommand.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.launch(Main.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.go(Main.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.main(Main.java:41)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.ClassCreation.callCreateMethod(ClassCreation.java:51)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.lambda$getClass$4(MemoizedConfig.java:104)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.getClass(MemoizedConfig.java:99)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.ConfigException: Driver setting 'Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\\}}' does not adhere to the required 'key=value' format!
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.lambda$addDriverConfigs$11(NodeOptions.java:388)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.addDriverConfigs(NodeOptions.java:370)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.getSessionFactories(NodeOptions.java:245)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNodeFactory.create(LocalNodeFactory.java:79)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        ... 17 more
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.getStatus()" because "this.node" is null
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.lambda$new$0(NodeServer.java:78)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```